# Recuperar SqlCommand como string

Tags: c#, .net

Eu preciso recuperar uma informação de BD com um select e comparar com o que o usuário está digitando caso sejam informações diferentes, permito o insert. Caso a comparação seja igual eu não deixo inserir e exibo mensagem de erro.

Segue abaixo o que estou tentando fazer:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" SELECT Porta FROM Equipamento WHERE Porta = txtPorta.Text", conn);

    string portacadastrada = cmd.ToString();

    string portatentativa = Convert.ToString(txtPorta.Text);

    if (portacadastrada == portatentativa)
    {
        ShowMessage("Porta já cadastrada.");

    }
```

Comment: Porque precisa converter *string* em *string*? Você quer fazer o que? Consultar o banco de dados, pegar o dado retornado e comparar com o que foi digitado? Aí não está consultado nada. E provavelmente não conseguiremos ajudar adequadamente só com esse trecho. O que já dá para ver é que essa consulta está bem errada e muito longe do que deveria ser. Na verdade acho que você tem bem mais problemas do que acha, já que esse código não faz o menor sentido. Me parece que está fazendo algo mais complexo do que você consegue. Precisa entender outras coisas mais básicas antes.

Comment: provavelmente um formulário, o usuário preenche informações para cadastro de um produto ou seja lá o que for. e você quer saber se este mesmo item já foi cadastrado previamente correto? no envio do formulário, você faz a verificação no seu script, roda um comando que procura pelo nome do produto usando like '%%' porque ele pode digitar o nome do produto errado tambem e ele cadastrar em duplicidade, mas com nome errado. acho que esse método que você usa pode ser melhorado, drasticamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SqlCommand** é para executar comandos como **Insert, Delete e Update** para recuperar informações você pode fazer da seguitne forma:

```
//Pega a porta digitada pelo usuario
var portaDigitada = txtPorta.Text;
//Monta o comando usando DataAdapter
var comando = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Porta FROM Equipamento WHERE Porta 
= @porta", conn);
comando.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@porta", portaDigitada);
//Cria um DataTable que vai armazenar o resultado do BD
        var dt = new DataTable();
//Preenche o datatable com o resultado do bd
        comando.Fill(dt);
//Pega o Valor que esta querendo, Onde Rows[0] é o numero da linha, Considerando que esta comando traga somente uma
        string portacadastrada = dt.Rows[0]["Porta"];
```

Comment: Eu quero exatamente isso que o Edenilson Bila falou. Eu preciso recuperar uma informação de BD e comparar com o que o usuário está digitando antes de fazer o insert. Caso a comparação seja igual eu não deixo inserir.

Comment: @DenisPolicarpo Eu corrigi o método, Vê se o postado acima lhe atende

Comment: @Edenilson Bila Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado! Eu só converti o dt.Rows[0]["Porta"] para string.